# Can somebody explain this C# constructor syntax - public Class1(Class 2 Obj) : this(obj.ToString())?

Tags: c#, methods, constructor, this

Here is the code:

```
class Class1
{    
    private Class2 object;

    public Class1(Class2 obj) : this(obj.ToString())
    {
        this.object = obj;
    }
}
```

More specifically, what does the `: this` part do.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This is a valid question for somebody new to development.

Comment: Run the code, then you'll know.

Comment: Clearly you haven't made a single search on to find the answer. This can be found in the simplest articles on MSDN about C#.

Comment: @thecoon - I did search on google and msdn links. I posted here after I couldn't find a satisfactory answer. Also it is much easier and faster to search on google than post on SO and format the code like it appears in an IDE, so that should tell you that I did search.

Comment: It's not always easy to search for things with non-alphanumeric characters like `:` I think this is a good question.

Comment: It's not a good question because *Stackoverflow should not be used as a substitute for a book/tutorial/class/etc*.   This is elementary C# knowledge and is inappropriate for this site.  Might as well ask the question, "What does `*` do in C#?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:this(obj.ToString)` causes the constructor code for the constructor defined taking a string parameter to run first.  Once it runs, then the constructor code (setting `this.object = obj`) is executed.

This is covered in [MSDN's page on Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) (the last example set).

Note that, in your code above, as written, this will cause a *compiler error.*  You would also need to have a constructor like the following:

```
public Class1(string str) // Constructor taking a string, though it could be non-public
{
    // Do something with str
}
```

With this constructor in place, it will get called, perform it's initialization steps, then the first constructor (which sets `this.object`) will run.

Answer (score 1):

`: this(obj.ToString())` calls overloaded version of constructor from same class.

It means that somewhere in this class you have another constructor which takes `string` as parameter and will be executed alongside current constructor.

```
class A
{
    public A(Class2 obj): this(obj.ToString()) // execute A(string text)
    {
        // your code
    }

    public A(string text)
    {
       // your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class 1 will have another constructor that takes a string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It calls the constructor that matches that syntax.  In your case, I'm assuming there's a constructor that takes a string argument somewhere:

```
public Class1(string s)
{ 
}
```